# C++ indicates my highest Shader Model is 3

Tags: c++, directx, shader

I'm trying to detect what's the highest Shader Model my Graphics Card has in C++ by using `if(caps.VertexShaderVersion < D3DVS_VERSION(i, 0)){return false;}` where i is the shader model I want to check, but I can only get it up to 3.

The problem is I've checked my Graphics Card (Gigabyte GeForce GTX 470) and it has DirectX 11 so shouldn't it have Shader Model 5? Or is there something wrong with the way I'm checking the Shader Model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Direct3D 9, which is the API you're using, is not aware of Direct3D 11's existence, therefore, it reports the highest supported shader version supported in D3D9.